# How can I replace Pipe (|) with space using regexp_replace in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata, regexp-replace

I would like to replace all pipes and line breaks with space in a free text field in my data base.

My current approach looks like the following:

`SELECT
ID,
REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(FREETEXT,'|',‘ ‘),‘\n',' ')
FROM TABLE`

My idea is to replace the pipes | with a space and then the results get checked again and all linebreaks are replaced. Problem now is that there are still pipes in there which messes up the CSV since my delimter for that is |.

Hope anyone can help me out here.

PS: I am not able to change the delimter to something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe symbol is a special character in a Regular Expression, splitting it into multiple alternatives, thus you must escape it.

If you want to replace all pipe and line break characters you don't have to nest:

```
RegExp_Replace(FREETEXT,'[\|\n\r]',' ')

\| pipe 0x7C
\n line feed 0x0A
\r carriage return 0x0D
```

But as those are single characters you can simply use

```
OTranslate(FREETEXT, '7C0A0D'xc,'   ')
```

Only if you want to replace consecutive occurences of those characters with a single space you need a RegEx:

```
RegExp_Replace(FREETEXT,'[\|\n\r]+',' ')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what does the + do at the end of your last example?

Comment: @MickyMaus: it replaces multiple consecutive characters with a single space, e.g. `'a|||b'` -> `'a b'` or a windows CRLF.

Comment: But it would also replace single characters right? Thanks again, this really helped me out.

Comment: @MickyMaus: Of couse, `+` means *at least one*